# Overload resolution error with DrawText

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, overload-resolution

While porting some code from D2007 to XE2 I got a compiler error I can't understand. Please see the following sample:

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  c: Char;
  pc: PChar;
  r: TRect;
begin
  c := '1';
  pc := @c;
  r := Bounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
  DrawText(Canvas.Handle, pc, 1, r, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_NOCLIP); //1
{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}
  DrawText(Canvas.Handle, @c, 1, r, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_NOCLIP); //2
{$TYPEDADDRESS ON}
  DrawText(Canvas.Handle, @c, 1, r, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_NOCLIP); //3
  DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(@c), 1, r, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_NOCLIP); //4
end;
```

D2007 compiles that without a problem. The XE2 compiler rejects the line marked `//3` with

> [DCC Fehler] Unit1.pas(38): E2010 Inkompatible Typen: 'string' und 'Pointer'

I guess that is due to the newly added `DrawText` overloads accepting Delphi strings.

Can you explain that error? It's no big problem as I have a workaround (explicit casting), but I'm curious. Is the error still present in later Delphi versions?

**Edit:** I'm asking **whether** there is an error in the compiler, not for an explanation **why** it is there. It might well be that I overlooked a valid reason for the compiler to reject my code.

Comment: I can confirm the same compiler error message in XE6 upd 1.

Comment: The error is quite odd, but I doubt anyone outside the compiler team can explain it. Sadly Delphi overloading resolution is not fully documented. I suppose that somebody may be able to reverse engineer a full description of the overloading resolution.

Comment: @David, see my edit. I tried to clarify what I'm asking. :-)

Comment: I don't even know how `@c` is treated in `//3`, or how the overload resolution is meant to work. So, if we cannot know how the overload resolution is meant to work, it's hard to judge whether this is a compiler bug or not. I might be wrong, but whenever I've looked at documentation for overload resolution I have found it to be incompletely described.

Comment: It seems easy to me: `c` is a `Char`, so `@c` is a `PChar`, so choose the overload that explicitly takes a `PChar`. I don't really see how line `//3` is different from `//1` or `//4` regarding overload resolution. `//2` is different as `@c` is an untyped pointer there.

Comment: There's all sorts of magic relating to character pointers. So, I've no idea what `@c` is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be a normal overload resolution situation.  `DrawText` is defined twice as :

```
function DrawText(hDC: HDC; 
                  lpString: PWideChar; 
                  nCount: Integer;
                  var lpRect: TRect; 
                  uFormat: UINT): Integer; external user32 name 'DrawTextW';

function DrawText(hDC: HDC; 
                  const lpString: UnicodeString; 
                  nCount: Integer;
                  var lpRect: TRect; uFormat: UINT): Integer;
begin
  Result := Winapi.Windows.DrawText(hDC, 
                                    PWideChar(lpString), 
                                    nCount, 
                                    lpRect, 
                                    uFormat);
end;
```

With `{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}` it seems that a `^Char` is interpreted by the compiler as an untyped `pointer` that is never compatible with a declared type of `PChar` while `@c` does seem to resolve to a `PChar` ok.  This seems at odds with the notion that `{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}` is meant to make all pointers type-agnostic.  It seems that `PChar` and `^Char` are somehow treated differently in the compiler than other pointers.

With `{$TYPEDADDRESS ON}` both `@c` and `^Char` become equivalent, but curiously are accepted as arguments so long as there is no overload resolution to sort out.

In both cases it seems that *overload resolutions are finalized before type-compatibility is fully established*.  I'm not sure I'd call it a bug, though... it seems like behaviour that would be tricky to change without causing problems.

SSCCE

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

{$DEFINE OVLD}

{$IFDEF OVLD}
procedure Test(s:string); overload;
begin
end;
{$ENDIF}
procedure Test(x:PChar); {$IFDEF OVLD}overload; {$ENDIF}
begin
end;

var
  c : Char;
  pc : ^Char;
begin
  {$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}
  Test(@c);
  Test(pc);    //OVLD - Incompatible types : 'string'-'pointer'
               //No OVLD - Incompat. types : 'PWideChar'-'pointer'
  {$TYPEDADDRESS ON}
  Test(@c);    //OVLD - Incompatible types : 'string'-'pointer'
               //No OVLD - OK
  Test(pc);    //OVLD - Incompatible types : 'string'-'pointer'
               //No OVLD - OK
end.
```

Comment: I guess you're right about the "tricky to change" part. :-) At least there's a simple backward compatible workaround.